# When should I define task handles/

Tags: freertos

I'm using FreeRTOS with an arduino UNO. I'm going through some of the examples from the FreeRTOS handbook and I've noticed that in a lot of the examples they dont define the Task handles. But in a lot of online examples i see people defining Task Handles.
[The main Function of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRGGC.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It's a hundred times more useful as text.

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You use task handles to reference one task from another.  For example, if you want to send a [direct to task notification](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notifications.html) to a task, or if you want one task to delete another task, then you need the task's handle.

Comment: Please do not post answer where the instructive part is purely in a link offsite. You should always put the content in your answer and link only as supporting evidence.